# VPC Peering in 2 different account via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc-peering

I try to set up a vpc peering connection between 2 VPC in Singapore region in 2 different AWS accounts. I followed the terraform document on "vpc_peering_connection" and "vpc_peering_connection_accepter" on the official website. So this is my code and failure:

**Requester**

```
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "requester" {
   provider = aws.anhvq
   vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
   peer_owner_id = "aws account id of accepter"
   # peer_region = "ap-southeast-1"
   peer_vpc_id = "vpc id of accepter"
   auto_accept = false

   tags = local.tags
   accepter {
   allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
 }
   requester {
   allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
 }
}
```

When I run `terraform plan` nothing fails. when run `terraform apply`, I receive this failure:

```
│ Error: Unable to modify peering options. The VPC Peering Connection "pcx-0e625f0fd4ef93696" is not active. 
Please set `auto_accept` attribute to `true`, or activate VPC Peering Connection manually. 
│
│   with aws_vpc_peering_connection.requester,
│   on vpc.tf line 49, in resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "requester":
│   49: resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "requester" {
│
╵
```

But the VPC Peering connection is still created and I got the VPC Peering ID

**Accepter**

```
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter" "accepter" {
    provider = aws.lamnx
    vpc_peering_connection_id = "pcx-0e625f0fd4ef93696"
    auto_accept = true
    accepter {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }
```

Result: `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` is done.

- The status of VPC peering in both Accounts is active. But when I run `terraform apply` again in **Requester**, the VPC peering was destroyed and replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolve myself. I read an issue on GitHub same as my issue. So I want to share with everybody how to fix it.
The reason is:

- Terraform not support enabling DNS resolve with vpc peering different accounts. It only supports with vpc peering in one account.
- I fix it by using `resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_options"`. This is my worked code:

```
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "requester" {
    provider = aws.anhvq
    vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
    peer_owner_id = "aws account id of accepter"
    # peer_region = "ap-southeast-1"
    peer_vpc_id = "vpc id of accepter"
    auto_accept = false

    tags = local.tags

}
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter" "accepter" {
    provider = aws.lamnx
    vpc_peering_connection_id = "${aws_vpc_peering_connection.requester.id}"
    auto_accept = true

    tags = local.tags
}
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_options" "requester" {
    provider = aws.anhvq
  vpc_peering_connection_id = "${aws_vpc_peering_connection.requester.id}"

  requester {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }
}
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_options" "accepter" {
  provider = aws.lamnx
  vpc_peering_connection_id = "${aws_vpc_peering_connection.requester.id}"

  accepter {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }
}
```